# db is not a function error in NodeJS using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got this error in my application that is previously working

```
const usersCollection = require('../db').db().collection("users")
                                         ^

TypeError: require(...).db is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/sites/app/models/User.js:2:42)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/sites/app/controllers/userController.js:1:14)
```

db.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
true}, function(err, client) {
module.exports = client
const app = require('./app')
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
})
```

.env file

```
CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb+srv://user:password@sandbox-gk8wp.mongodb.net/db? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority
PORT=3000
```

I have updated also my mongodb npm package from 3.3.3 to 3.4.1 but still the same error. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: There's a lot going on in your code that could be improved. Are you following any sort of tutorial to get started? While your db.js should (and does) contain the details about connecting to the database it isn't the right place for the app declaration. But you're getting that error because the db.js doesn't have a function called db() defined.

Comment: Hi Steve, yes I followed tutorial for this and added some. This is a working and published app last year then suddenly breaks. I have reviewed my commits and check all the same. I can't figure out. I am trying now to change code of my db connection.

Comment: Please check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709431/syntaxerror-await-is-only-valid-in-async-function-when-connecting-to-mongo-db/59709838#59709838 , From that you need to export `newFunction` in db file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to export something in the callback which may or may not be available when you import it as it is asynchronous method. Better way will be to create `db.js` like

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

function getMongoClient() {
  return mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
}

module.exports = getMongoClient;
```

And when you want to use it

```
const getMongoClient = require('../db');

getMongoClient()
  .then(client => client.db().collection("users"));
```

Hope this helps. You could also use `async/await`.